# Javascript Warp Time with Warp js

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where I need to manipulate time speed forward and backward. This module seems like what I need but I can't get it working:

https://github.com/mattbradley/warpjs/blob/master/README.md

Any help appreciated

```
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>

    <body>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="warp.js"></script>


        <div id="container"></div>
        <span id="info"></span><br>
        <span id="time"></span>
        <span id="time2"></span>

        <script>


      setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date;
        now = Date.warp.clock(true);
        //now = Date.warp.speed(2); // DOESNT WORK?

        var dateD = [now.getMonth() + 1,now.getDate(),now.getFullYear()];
        var dateE = [now.getHours(),now.getMinutes(),now.getSeconds()];
        var MDY = dateD.join("/");
        var HMS = dateE.join(":");
        time.innerHTML = (MDY);
        time2.innerHTML = (HMS);

      }, 20);


        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should read the documentation again? I'm not sure what the unexpected behavior is here.

Comment: Maybe you should read it before you comment? It's pretty obvious what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: What do you expect the return value of `Date.warp.speed(2)` to be?

Comment: Date.warp.speed([speed])

The speed() function gets or sets the tick speed of the warped clock. Sending no arguments will return the current tick speed. The speed argument can be thought of as a multiplicative factor: setting the speed to 2 will make the clock tick at 2 seconds per second -- or twice as fast. Negative speeds make the clock tick backwards. <-- that?

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't return a `Date` object, which would have `getMonth` etc. You need to set `now` to be a `Date` object. Right now you are overwriting `now` to something else.

Comment: Isn't that what this line does? var now = new Date;

Comment: Yes, but then `now = Date.warp.speed(2);` overwrites it.

Comment: I follow. Got it fixed below. Thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrap is a static method, it doesn't return any value(`undefined` is returned)

```
setInterval(function() {
  Date.warp.speed(3);
  var now = new Date;

  var dateD = [now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate(), now.getFullYear()];
  var dateE = [now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()];
  var MDY = dateD.join("/");
  var HMS = dateE.join(":");
  time.innerHTML = (MDY);
  time2.innerHTML = (HMS);

}, 1000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/88ejd81y/)

Comment: Thanks! That did it.

Comment: Hey man, how would I warp time from a pre-defined date that isn't today? Every time I want to update the display with new Date(); it overwrites to today?

Comment: Say, I wanted to start this time warp from 5/6/1986?